# Query grouped entity with max value

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework

I have an entity BattleUser which contains four properties: Id, BattleId, UserId and DateTime. I need to query the last (by date) BattleUser entity for every user. So I came to something like this:

```
context.GroupBy(bu => bu.UserId, bu => bu).
Select(gbu => new { UserId = gbu.Key, DateTime = gbu.Max(bu => bu.DateTime) }).
ToList();
```

By this query I retrieve the last DateTime for each user. By using these values I can retrieve last BattleUser entities for every user by another query. Is there any way to modify initial query to solve the task by one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this query:

```
context.GroupBy(bu => bu.UserId, bu => bu)
    .Select(gbu => new
    {
       UserId = gbu.Key,
       LastBattleUser = gbu.OrderByDescending(bu => bu.DateTime).FirstOrDefault()
    })
    .ToList();
```